# What is an isomorphic application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I have been reading multiple different articles about what Isomorphic application is, why this type of architecture is better and so forth. But I still have a bit of uncertainty as to what is meant by such term.

**How would you define what "Isomorphic Application" is, without going too much into details?**

Comment: It's the interchangeability between Javascript frameworks you tagged this question as, i.e. They are used on the server as well as on the client.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are, more recently, also called `universal`.  I'm not sure about the whole app being called isomorphic/universal, but you can certainly have parts of the code base that is universal.

Isomorphic/universal code is code that runs on both the client (browser) and on the server (NodeJS).  Since they are both JavaScript this something that is possible if:

1. you do not mention `window`, `document` or any other browser-only methods
2. you do not mention `server`, `fs` or any or any other node-only methods.
3. If you do need to do the above within some code that is meant to be universal, you should wrap it in a function that either mocks the required method within the alternate environment or wrap it in conditionals so that the app doesn't crash.

An example is `console.log` which will work both within NodeJS and any browser, along with most other es6 methods in modern browsers.

I use build tools (like webpack) to then help create / export functions within individual files so that we then have a `bundle` like `client-app.js` which is included in the HTML file and is the browser only js.  The server then might start using `server-app.js` which is the server-only bundle.  Both bundles can be created using a lot of the same `universal` source code.